# __attribute__((constructor)) functions and autorelease

Tags: objective-c, constructor, autorelease

If I create and use some Objective-C classes in an `__attribute__((constructor))` function and they potentially create some auto-released objects, is it safe to put an `@autorelease` block around this code in the constructor function even though this will be called before `main`?

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink this, and refactor some things in a way that this craziness isn't required.

Comment: Why is this crazy? I want to create a singleton that listens for some notifications and does its thing automatically, so that users of my class simply need to include the .m file and do nothing else. Seems a perfectly sensible way to achieve this. I actually found an example that does this already called `BPOCUnitXMLReporter`, which *doesn't* wrap the code in the constructor function - I guess nothing it uses creates any autoreleased objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, `main()`'s `@autorelease` block isn't in any way more special than the ones in any other part of the code, so I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: It seems you are right - I was unsure about a) how early on the constructor functions are called; and b) if it's ok to have the first `@autorelease` block end before `main` and then another one start in `main`. Reading up on this and thinking about it more, `main` is just a function like any other. The constructors are called before `main` is, but everything is "ready-to-go" already so you can do anything you might do in the top of `main`.